# android monitoring apps

Tags: android

I would like to create an Android application with real-time monitoring functions.  One monitoring function is to audit the audio flow.  The other function is to interact with a peripheral sensor.  These monitoring functions can be triggered by others. 
Besides, in order to save power consumption, the audio function will be running in a polling mode, i.e. sleep for a certain amount of time and wake for a certain amount of time.

I am considering how to design the Android application.

- Whether to design the audio function as a Service or an Activity? 
  The problem is if it is designed as an Activity, the audio function will be off if screen turns off after a period of time.
- How to design the polling function? Use an AlarmManager or a inner-thread with Timer?

My goal is to save the power consumption as much as possible. Thanks.

Comment: What is "audit the audio flow"?

Comment: use the AudioRecord to read the audio buffer flow and audit the decibel level and make the log. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend following

a) Use a Service. Activity is short lived entity (it works only while it's on the screen)

b) Make the service foreground (read this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification). This will decrease the chance that system will kill your service

c) In the service, start a thread and do everything you need in the thread.

d) If you want execute periodically, just do Thread.sleep() in the thread (when Thread sleeps it doesn't consume CPU cycles).

I believe c) and d) is preferable to AlarmManager.
Here is piece from documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) : "Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler."

Since your application running it's better to have some permanently running thread and execute something on it. Generally speaking Handler, HandlerThread, MessageQueue are just convenience classes for more complex message handling and scheduling. It looks like your case is quite simple and usual Thread should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Concurring with Victor, you definitely want to use a Service, and pin it into memory by calling `startForeground()`

However I suggest you look into utilizing the built in system `Handler` ; place your functionality in a `Runnable` and call `mhandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, <some point in future>)` ; this will allow the android framework to make the most of power management.

Answer (score 0):

That's a service.

And you may want some extra robustness: the service can be killed and *NOT* restarted later, even being a foreground service.  That will stop your monitoring.

Start your service from the UI.  If you want the service to survive device reboot, also start it from a BroadcastReceiver for android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED.

Create a thread in the service as described in other answers here.

Additionally, use Alarm Manager to periodically start your service again.  Multiple startService() calls are OK. If already running, the service will keep running.  But if it's been forgotten by the system, say, after a series of low resource conditions, it will be restarted now.

Schedule those alarms responsibly: to be a good citizen, set the absolutely minimal frequency.  After all, Android had some good reasons to kill the service.

With some services, even more steps may be needed, but in this case this approach seems to be sufficient.